# Issue authenticating using default providers with a Static Blazor Webassembly app - "Sorry, there's nothing at this address."

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have followed almost half a dozen examples in attempting to spin up a default Blazor Webassembly static site locally in Visual Studio so I can test out the authentication providers.

According to all the examples I have seen, after adding this line in startup -

```
builder.Services.AddStaticWebAppsAuthentication();
```

And then a quick modification to App.razor -

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

You should now be able to run the application and go to  `https://localhost:7098/.auth/login/aad` and be redirected to the MS login. Instead I always get an error of **"Sorry, there's nothing at this address."**, with this error in the browser console

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

One attempt I tried has an MS YouTube video and associated repo with all the code implemented (https://github.com/FBoucher/AzureStaticWebApp-CSharp-SimpleDemo). If I download the code, load it in VS and F5, I *still* get the exact same issue.

A few tutorials reference this package - https://anthonychu.ca/post/blazor-auth-azure-static-web-apps/ which I have, again, followed through and done multiple times, but still I get the same issue.

If someone has any idea can you please point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: look for blazor wasm state authentication service, Tim Corey goes into in detail on YouTube

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was never able to get this working. No matter how many examples I looked at, the default auth provider logic would never work correctly as I described above.

In the end I attempted what should be the more complex approach of setting up my own custom authentication logic using app registrations (this is where I wanted to end up anyway) and this did work! I followed this MS guide to achieve this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this works when running locally with Visual Studio out of the box.

You will need to install https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli which provides a mock for the /.Auth routes, and possibly also need to use VSCode.  Follow the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/local-development

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).